# How to run ffmpeg in a loop and test it for error?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, video, ffmpeg

I have stuttering, seeking, and general playback issues when playing large mkv files through my Plex Media Server setup. I have been looking around for a way to automate scheduled tasks to move everything to mp4. The objective is:

Copy mkv files into mp4 preserving subtitles of every kind. Put the new file in the same subdir, and delete previous mkv version if conversion went successful.

When I tried to run ffmpeg on a loop, I run into the problem described here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36310/strange-errors-when-using-ffmpeg-in-a-loop

This is my first adventure on shell scripting and I am pretty much stumbling around and trying to understand the syntax and philosophy of it. What I understand is that they use a file descriptor to redirect ffmpeg output to /dev/null.

The problem with that solution is that I would need to check ffmpeg output for errors to decide whether to delete the previous file or not. Furthermore, there is a common error when converting from picture based subtitles streams, which I circumvent by using a script I found (http://www.computernerdfromhell.com/blog/automatically-extract-subtitles-from-mkv/) to work after some modifications to my needs.

After much frustration I ended modifying the script so much that it does not serve to its purpose. It does not check for errors. Anyways, I will post it here. Mind you that this is my first shell script ever, and almost everything is confusing about it. The problem with this, is that I had to ditch my error checking and I am eliminating files that errored when converting. Losing the original without a valid copy.

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDERS=( "/mnt/stg4usb/media0/test/matroska1" "/mnt/stg4usb/media0/test/season1" "/mnt/stg4usb/media0/test/secondtest")
FLAGS="-y -metadata title="" -c:v copy -map 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -movflags +faststart"
COUNTER=0

LOGFILE=batch-$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S").log

for FOLDER in "${FOLDERS[@]}"
do

    echo "---===> STARTING folder: '$FOLDER'"

    find $FOLDER -name "*.mkv" | while read line; do

        OUTPUT=""
        DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
        TIME=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
        COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
        FILE=$(basename "$line")
        DIR=$(dirname "${line}")

        echo $'\n'$'\n'"[$COUNTER][$DATE][$TIME][FILE:'${line%.mkv}.mp4']"$'\n'

        echo "#### Transcoding ####"'\n'
        ffmpeg -i $line $FLAGS -sn "${line%.mkv}.mp4" < /dev/null


        echo "#### Extracting subtitles ###"'\n''\n'
        mkvmerge -i "$line" | grep 'subtitles' | while read subline
        do
            # Grep the number of the subtitle track
            tracknumber=`echo $subline | egrep -o "[0-9]{1,2}" | head -1`

            # Get base name for subtitle
            subtitlename=${line%.*}

            # Extract the track to a .tmp file
            mkvextract tracks "$line" $tracknumber:"$subtitlename.$tracknumber.srt" < /dev/null
            chmod g+rw "$subtitlename.$tracknumber"* < /dev/null
        done

        rm -frv "$line" < /dev/null

        echo "Finished: $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")"

    done

    echo '\n'"<===--- DONE with folder: '$FOLDER'"$'\n'$'\n' >> $LOGFILE

done

exit 0
```

So, basically, the idea is: run ffmpeg on a loop for all mkv under a directory and subdirectories (I was using find). Check it for all possible errors. If errors, try again without subtitles and extract the subtitles using mkvextract, else everything went ok, and delete the previous file.

Comment: you know that you can conditionally run a program inside an `if` test? i.e. `if mkvextract ; then echo No problems running mkvextract ; else echo error running mkvextract ; fi` ? But what I would do is capture std-in/std-err to a tmpfile, and then `if grep -qE 'Errmsg1|errmsg2|....|...|' /tmp/stdinStdErrTmp.$$ ; then echo "found an error, doing alternate processing path" ; alternateProcesses ; else echo No errors found in /tmp/stdinStdErrTmp.$$ ; /bin/rm /tmp/stdinSTdErrTmp.$$ ; fi` . Hope that gives you an idea. If you have trouble with `grep -qE 'err1|err2|..` etc post a new Q w just that.GL

Comment: I already tried with a temp file in the same subdir. I put the output in it and then read that output. Yet, still got the issue mentioned. FFmpeg reads garbage. It is explained here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36310/strange-errors-when-using-ffmpeg-in-a-loop

Comment: Not really sure which part of that Q is appropriate to your problem. Can't you turn this into one line of code/input/ouput that you need to fix? My (limited) experience with `ffmpeg` also tells me that you need to combine stdin/stderr with `ffmpeg ...options... 2>&1 >/tmp/stdinStdErrTmp.$$` Does that help? Else, can't really believe that a bug is producing 'c` chars for input. Much more likely there is another explanation, unless it is a well-known problem on the ffmpeg support forum. Good luck!

Comment: I don't have the time to debug all of this, but I think having nested while loops may also be a problem. Just did a search for `[bash] nested while loop` and there are 50 Q/As. Maybe you'll find something there.

Comment: Don't worry, I understand, any help is deeply appreciated. I certainly have to sit down and study shell scripting. Anyways, I don't have a clear idea of what it is meant by this, but this comes from the previously linked question about ffmpeg on a loop: "The bash script seems to produce input (Namely the 'c' key) which interferes with the ffmpeg process."

Comment: can you isolate 1 of the calls to `ffmpeg` that is dealing with the 'c' key issue? If so, edit your Q (at the bottom) to show that 1 command. Rather than use $varNames for files etc, replace all of those with actual values. Does it still have a problem? Also, include any relevant output from ffmpeg. Would be good to know what version you are using.

Comment: Willing to help you with this, but as is, will need to understand a way to set up a test environment where we're both getting the same results for each set of inputs. I would say don't worry about `mkvextract` until you get the error trapping working as needed for `ffmpeg`. I'm in CST and going to bed soon, what is your schedule like?